# Test ExpressionSet from Apex Unit test

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow, automation

I have below in the code

1. On Case create/update- I have a flow that calls [express set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.248.0.industries_reference.meta/industries_reference/expression_set_parent.htm)
2. I am inserting Case from Apex class
3. I have written Apex test class which inserts Case

What's happening -
Currently the apex test is failing from expression set. Salesforce is kind enough to show helpful messages -
[image]
AND
[image]

What I know -
I know that it is not able to test expression set (which is not my motive anyway). It is calling the flow and then expression set but failing from expression set.

What I tried-

1. When I try to run this test as SeeAllData=true then it passes.
2. When I deactivate this flow then also my apex test passes
3. I saw that expression sets can be called as Rest POST call so I thought salesforce shall be using the same from flow to call expression set internally. Hence I simulated the expression set with my inputs, downloaded json output, and used HttpCalloutMock to create a mock class where I pasted this JSON Output.

None of these worked.
How can I test this apex test class which creates a case. The expression set is becoming a bottleneck. Anyone knows how to simulate or mock it from apex class.

Comment: Does the test depend on the ExpressionSet flow running? If not, gate your flow entry condition with a custom permission and have the apextest use a running user that has that custom permission.  Also, please excerpt the error message into direct text in the OP rather than screen shot